# RStudio won't launch on Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed R from CRAN and RStudio Desktop from [www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) (like anyone else would) for my MacBook Pro (running 12.0.1) and I can't launch RStudio. When I open the app, the icon spins for a bit and then says "R is taking longer to start than usual", with two buttons for either "Reload" or "Terminate R". If I click "Terminate R", I get the following
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1qfL.jpg).

I installed RStudio version 2021.09.1+372 and R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01).

I've been told to run `which R` and `which RStudio`, doing so returns `/usr/local/bin/R` and `RStudio not found`.

I've also tried installing R and RStudio from Brew, which resulted in the same problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you run R directly from R.app? Did you install X-Quartz?

Comment: I can run R directly, and I did install X-Quartz.

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling R-Studio and reinstalling. I'm using the same versions of R, R Studio, and MacOs on my iMac without any difficulty.

Comment: I've tried that many times but it's not working. I also tried uninstalling Xtools and reinstalling and that didn't work either.